# Excel Loop, Calculate and Colour Macro Skipping Cells

Tags: excel, vba

In row 9 I have a set of standard benchmark numerical values but not all cells are populated. In rows 10 to 29 are a set of test results but sometimes not all rows will be populated and/or not all cells within rows will be populated. Example image attached.

I have put together the following code to loop through the range and highlight test results that are either 5-10%, 10-15% or 15+% greater than the benchmarks or 5-10%, 10-15% or 15+% lower than the benchmarks.

It seems to work for some results but skips others. Can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

```
Sub HighlightStats()
   Dim r As Long, c As Long
   
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
   
    For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= Cells(9, c) * 1.05 And Cells(r, c) < Cells(9, c) * 1.1 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 222, 241)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= Cells(9, c) * 1.1 And Cells(r, c) < Cells(9, c) * 1.15 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
      Next c
   Next r
   
    For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= Cells(9, c) * 1.5 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 145, 208)
      Next c
   Next r
   
    For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= Cells(9, c) * 0.95 And Cells(r, c) > Cells(9, c) * 0.9 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(237, 219, 236)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= Cells(9, c) * 0.9 And Cells(r, c) > Cells(9, c) * 0.85 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 189, 221)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 10 To 29
      For c = 4 To 63
         If Cells(9, c) <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= Cells(9, c) * 0.85 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(207, 157, 205)
      Next c
   Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You should check for `Cells(r, c) <> ""` **before** `Cells(r, c) <= Cells(9, c)`.

Comment: And all your loops can be simplified into one loop, and you write `With` but you don't use it.

Comment: But mainly this should be *1.15*: `Cells(9, c) * 1.5` (loop 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put all loops into one and fixed your Parameters (1.15 should have been 1.5):

```
Sub HighlightStats()

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim sngCell As Single

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
        For r = 10 To 29
            For c = 4 To 63
                sngCell = Cells(9, c).Value
                If sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= Cells(9, c) * 1.15 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 145, 208)
                ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= sngCell * 1.1 And Cells(r, c) < sngCell * 1.15 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
                ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= sngCell * 1.05 And Cells(r, c) < sngCell * 1.1 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 222, 241)
                ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= sngCell * 0.95 And Cells(r, c) > sngCell * 0.9 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(237, 219, 236)
                ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= sngCell * 0.9 And Cells(r, c) > sngCell * 0.85 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 189, 221)
                ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) <= sngCell * 0.85 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(207, 157, 205)
                End if
             Next c
        Next r
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. I get a "Compile error: Else without If" on this line: ElseIf sngCell <> "" And Cells(r, c) >= sngCell * 1.1 And Cells(r, c) < sngCell * 1.15 And Cells(r, c) <> "" Then

Comment: @rob It was missing end if

Comment: Are you sure about that "1.5" value? The value 1.5 stands for 50%, the question mentions 15%, which corresponds with the value "1.15", not "1.5". In top of that, there's the value "0.85" (which corresponds with -15%.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified the multiple loops into one loop, removed the redundant `With..End With` statements, corrected an incorrect inequality, and improved the logic unit.

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long
For r = 10 To 29
    For c = 4 To 63
        If Cells(9, c) = "" Or Cells(r, c) = "" Then Next c
         
        If Cells(r, c) >= Cells(9, c) * 1.05 Then
            If Cells(r, c) < Cells(9, c) * 1.1 Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 222, 241)
            ElseIf Cells(r, c) < Cells(9, c) * 1.15 Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
            Else: Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 145, 208)
        End If

        If Cells(r, c) <= Cells(9, c) * 0.95 Then
            If Cells(r, c) > Cells(9, c) * 0.9 Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(237, 219, 236)
            ElseIf Cells(r, c) > Cells(9, c) * 0.85 Then Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 189, 221)
            Else: Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(207, 157, 205)
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't even start looking at the code, because a new feature has been added to Excel in order to handle such situations automatically, it's called conditional formatting, and it's explained in [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

In case you have problems getting it realised, there are plenty of questions on that subject here on the site, there even is a "conditional-formatting" tag foreseen for it.

Good luck

Comment: Well it is certainly not ‘new’, but it is certainly the solution.